# E-Mail: Send copy to sender - Swift

Tags: swift, email, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am using `MFMailComposeViewController` to send an email to someone's email address which was entered by the app's user munally.
Can I send a copy of that email to the sender of the email (the user)?

**Note:**

- I know, I cannot get the user's email address for privacy reasons.
- I'm looking for a way that spares the user entering his own email address

Comment: If sending the email to the app's user is something the user might do regularly, you could ask the user one time for their email address and then add it to the CC field automatically. Otherwise, it's the user's choice if they want a copy of their own email.

Comment: Yeah I've already implemented this as workaround until someone comes around with a solution...thanks anyway :)

Comment: What solution are you hoping for? You already know there is no way to get the user's email without asking them for it. So that means you must ask them for it. If you are already asking them for it, what solution do you want?

Comment: Well I hoped there'd be some function Apple wrote that allows us to do that which I haven't discovered yet. `MFMailComposeViewController.sendToSender` for instance, or whatever. But it seems like I need to accept the fact that there's none.